# Running python script using Cron in Beagelbone black

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, beagleboneblack

I add this line to crontab -e

```
* * * * * /root/Desktop/New.py
```

The New.py code is simple creating a text file here is the code of it

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f= open("test.txt",'w')
f.write("test")
f.close()
```

when I test executing the code using the shell it works correctly and when I tested the Cron using echo to a text file the Cron also works correctly, and I set the python file permission to executable, But still it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think whats happening is the `cwd` is not what you are expecting it to be. Try an explicit `cd` to a directory where you want the file to be created

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * cd /root/Desktop; /root/Desktop/New.py
```

Comment: I changed the New.py file to
f= open("/root/Desktop/test.txt",'w') and it is working as expected thanks

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
* * * * * python /root/Desktop/New.py
```

or this

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; python /root/Desktop/New.py
```